# IEEE Floating Point Sign?

Tags: binary, computer-science, ieee-754, base-conversion, ieee

Heyy, I am working on an assignment which requires me to convert floating point numbers to binary representation using IEEE Float Representation. I am able to convert floating point from decimal system to binary but on one part I have to convert 0.001111111 (Base 2) into IEEE Floating Representation.

I first normalized the number and got the exponential part as well as the mantissa part but I cannot determine the bit for the sign of the number as the actual float number is not given. Is there a way to determine whether the number is a negative or a positive from the given information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 0.00111111 (base 2) is positive. -0.00111111 would be the negation.